# How can I redirect to another page after verifying the credit card validation?

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, validation, credit-card

### I need help about redirect another page after credit card valitaditon success.php
Well i dont know anything about vue.
i found something like (onSubmit () {
axios.get('success.php', { )
Something like this? Any help to this poor guy. Thanks :)

Here is vue codes.

```js
  <script src="../dist/vue-credit-card-validation.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
    const Example = {
      computed: {
        cardBrandClass(){
          return this.getBrandClass(this.cardBrand);
        }
      },
      data() {
        return {
          cardNumber: null,
          cardExpiry: null,
          cardCvc: null,
          cardPostal: null,
          cardErrors: {},
          // declaring card-brand in data{} enables card brand name/classes.
          cardBrand: null,
        } 
      },
      methods: {
        validate: function(){

          // init
          this.cardErrors = {};
          
          // validate card number
          if(!this.$cardFormat.validateCardNumber(this.cardNumber)){
            this.cardErrors.cardNumber = "Invalid Credit Card Number.";
          };

          // validate card expiry
          if (!this.$cardFormat.validateCardExpiry(this.cardExpiry)) {
            this.cardErrors.cardExpiry = "Invalid Expiration Date.";
          };

          // validate card CVC
          if (!this.$cardFormat.validateCardCVC(this.cardCvc)) {
            this.cardErrors.cardCvc = "Invalid CVC.";
          };

        },
        reset: function(){
          this.cardErrors = {};
          this.cardNumber = null;
          this.cardExpiry = null;
          this.cardCvc = null;
          this.cardPostal = null;
          this.$refs.cardNumInput.focus();
        },
        prefill: function(ccNum){
          this.cardNumber = ccNum;
          this.$cardFormat.setCardType({
            currentTarget : this.$refs.cardNumInput,
            value: ccNum
          });
        },
        getBrandClass: function (brand) {
          let icon = '';
          brand = brand || 'unknown';
          let cardBrandToClass = {
            'visa': 'fab fa-cc-visa',
            'mastercard': 'fab fa-cc-mastercard',
            'amex': 'fab fa-cc-amex',
            'discover': 'fab fa-cc-discover',
            'diners': 'fab fa-cc-diners-club',
            'jcb': 'fab fa-cc-jcb',
            'unknown': 'fa fa-credit-card',
          };
          if (cardBrandToClass[brand]) {
            icon = cardBrandToClass[brand];
          };

          return icon;
        }
      },
      watch: {
        // handle auto-focus to next field
        // Note: since CVC can be 3 OR 4 digits we don't watch it
        cardNumber: function(val){
          if(this.$cardFormat.validateCardNumber(val)){
            this.$refs.cardExpInput.focus();
          }
        },
        cardExpiry: function (val) {
          if (this.$cardFormat.validateCardExpiry(val)) {
            this.$refs.cardCvcInput.focus();
          }
        }
      },
      onMounted(){
        this.$refs.cardNumInput.focus();
      } 
    };
    const app = createApp(Example);
    app.use(VueCreditCardValidation);
    app.mount('#app');
  </script>
```

```html
Here is html

  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Card validation</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <!-- Libraries only required for demo. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form >
            <div class="row pt-4">
              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Card Number:</label>
                  <div class="input-group mb-0">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i :class="cardBrandClass"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input ref="cardNumInput" :data-error="(cardErrors.cardNumber)?true:false" v-model="cardNumber" type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="#### #### #### ####" v-cardformat:formatCardNumber>
                  </div>
                  <div v-if="cardErrors.cardNumber" class="error">
                    <small>{{ cardErrors.cardNumber }}</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pt-2">
              <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Card Expiration:</label>
                  <input ref="cardExpInput" id="card-exp" :data-error="(cardErrors.cardExpiry)?true:false" v-model="cardExpiry" maxlength="10" class="form-control" v-cardformat:formatCardExpiry>
                  <div v-if="cardErrors.cardExpiry" class="error">
                    <small>{{ cardErrors.cardExpiry }}</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-4 col-lg-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Card CVC:</label>
                  <input ref="cardCvcInput" :data-error="(cardErrors.cardCvc)?true:false" v-model="cardCvc" class="form-control" v-cardformat:formatCardCVC>
                  <div v-if="cardErrors.cardCvc" class="error">
                    <small>{{ cardErrors.cardCvc }}</small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Restrict Numeric:</label>
                  <input placeholder="Only numbers can be entered here..." v-model="cardPostal" class="form-control" v-cardformat:restrictNumeric>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 pt-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="validate">Validate Card Details</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" @click="reset">Reset</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
          </body>
          </html>
```

I need help after validation confirm send to success.php page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with php/html files instead of an single page app, you could simply redirect the user with some basic javascript.
In your method, when you need to redirect the user after validating the card succesfully, just type:

```js
window.location.replace("http://my-url.com/my.page");
```